# How to setup local parse-server (open source) for file upload?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

Currently I have parse-server running ok locally, with the following settings:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: process.env.DATABASE_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/yacht',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: 'MyApp',
  masterKey: 'master_key',
});
```

The issue I am having is that when I attempt to upload a file like I did on the hosted Parse, I get the following error on the server:

> Uncaught internal server error. { [Error: request entity too large]

I am inferring I need to pass:

```
  filesAdapter: filesAdapter
```

To the server initialized in node... But I think theres more and I don't have a clue how to get the filesAdapter instantiated.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: HI kiko, if i download the parse server from github, would that just work or needs any sort of configuration? i am trying node index.js but dont get anything

Comment: Try again now (without the filesAdapter option). There have been many fixes for file uploads since you posted the question.

Comment: I have it working now. Simple fix in a limit of how much memory can be used by the library fixed it. It is now pushed in the main repo.

Comment: @Amir If you follow the parse guide, it is fairly straight forward.

Comment: --> This issue is fixed in the last release of the Parse Server

Comment: Did you use Amazon or your own server?